# Creating a button that commits an input field's text to my state in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using React to build a simple clone of Reddit. Right now I am working on creating a button to sign a user up to the website. The button's `onClick` event needs to trigger a function which takes the value of an input field and store the value in the state. I'm sure it's very simple to implement but I haven't been able to figure it out.

I've tried reading documentation and Googling around (mostly StackOverflow links) but I haven't found an answer yet.

Here are some snippets of my code:

```
class App extends Component {
    state = {
        username: "",
        loggedIn: false
    }

    signUp = () => {
        this.setState({ loggedIn: !this.state.loggedIn });
    };

    handleChange = event => {
        this.setState({
            username: event.target.value
        });
    };

// ... things have been excluded ...

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="App">
                <div className="Header">
                    <p className="Logo">Reddit Clone</p>
                    {this.state.loggedIn ? null : (
                        <div style={{ float: "right" }}>
                            <input
                                type="text"
                                name="Username"
                                onChange={this.handleChange}
                            ></input>
                            <button onClick={this.signUp}>Sign Up</button>
                        </div>
                    )}
                </div>
                <div style={{ margin: "20px" }}>{threads}</div>
                {postBox}
            </div>
        );
    }
```

I expect the answer will look something like what it does now, maybe just one or two lines of code to get a solution. I've seen similar things done in tutorials but none of them are quite what I need. Hopefully someone can help.

Again, I basically want the "Sign Up" button to transmit the adjacent input fields' text value to my state so I can use the info later.

Comment: You already have the value of username in state. `this.state.username` has the value of your user and the input box present in your component

Answer (score 1):

Change the signUp function into this:

```
signUp = (e) => {
e.preventDefault() //its for preventing browser refreshing the page by default
            this.setState({ loggedIn: !this.state.loggedIn,
                             username:this.state.username
 });
        };
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the previous comment, after the button in your component fires the onClick function you will have both **username** and **loggedIn** in the state. for test purposes, add this piece of code and watch the status of state

```
componentDidUpdate(){
  console.log(this.state)
}
```

Temporray [sample sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/great-glade-3obhz)